# Hide overflow of dropdown options

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor

I have a dropdown list of names but if a name is too long, the list distorts the page. To combat this, i wish to hide the overflow of each option or add an ellipsis if the name is too long. Ive tried `text-overflow: hidden;` but I cannot get it to work, any help appreciated!

```
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <select class="form-control" id="addWatcherSelect" data-e2e="groups-details-assign-watcher" style="text-overflow:ellipsis;" asp-items="@Model.UnassignedWatchers">
                                <option value="0" selected="selected">Assign New Watcher</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-icon-split" id="addWatcherBtn" data-e2e="groups-details-add-watcher">
                                    <span class="text">Add</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>

               $("button[id$='addWatcherBtn']").on('click', function (e) {
                let leagueId = $('#addWatcherSelect option:selected').val();
                if (leagueId) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("AddWatcher", "GroupsApi", new { id = Model.GroupId })',
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: JSON.stringify(leagueId),
                        success: function (result) {
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

To manage the height of a div, and to show a vertical scroll bar only when needed, add this to your input-group css class(change the px value as needed).

```
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
```

For the option, you may want to assign a (new) css class, and these properties (changing the px value as needed):

```
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't apply styling to options in select elements.You can refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35349063/how-make-select-box-smaller-when-option-is-too-long).

Maybe you can try to shorten the length of innerHTML of options with js:

```
$(function () {
            $("option").each(function (index, item) {
                if (item.innerHTML.length > 80) {
                    item.innerHTML = item.innerHTML.substring(0, 80)+"...";
                }
            })
        })
```